# Upgrading Realm from 2.3.1 to 3.2.1 with Proguard

Tags: realm

I just upgraded Realm Java from 2.3.1 to 3.2.1 and this caused issues with deobsfucation. I start getting:

**IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query: table 'PlaceRealm' not found in this schema.**

If I add the following proguard rules before the upgrade, there are no issues.

```
-keepnames public class * extends io.realm.RealmObject
-keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
```

In both the 2.3.1 and 3.2.1 documentations, it says the proguard configuration is automatically sorted.

I don't fully understand why this problem happened. Does anyone know why this happened? I would like to understand to prevent it happening again.

Also this may be helpful to someone else.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a bug introduced by a big refactor in 3.2.0 ( https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4673 ), it'll be fixed eventually.

Comment: Ha, I hadn't upgraded for months. What are the chances I upgraded 2 days after a major bug :-(. Thanks for the issue link. I'll read through it. Cheers.

Comment: eh, this is why I point people to `3.1.4` for now :D

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Realm 3.2.0 and 3.2.1,  but if you update to Realm 3.3.0 then it should be fixed.

---

By the way, if you're curious, I tend to use the following Proguard configuration for Realm, which would have prevented this (although you generally don't need it):

```
#realm 0.82.2
-keepnames public class * extends io.realm.RealmObject
-keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
-keep class io.realm.** { *; }
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn io.realm.**

#realm 0.84.1+
-keep class io.realm.annotations.RealmModule
-keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
-keep class io.realm.internal.Keep
-keep @io.realm.internal.Keep class *
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn io.realm.**

#realm 0.89.0+
-keep class io.realm.RealmCollection
-keep class io.realm.OrderedRealmCollection
```